# T-test against normalised or standardised data gives different results

Tags: statistics, normalization, hypothesis-testing, twitter, pvalue

I am studying the problem to predict popularity of a tweet, and want to test null hypothesis: there is no relationships between favorite_counts and another set of variables, like number of friends of users.

I am not sure if normalise or standardise the variables, because I am thinking how to model popularity and don't know how the distributions of likes and friends among users are (please advise).

So I tried the two, and tried an independent t_test.

I get very different results:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
do_scaled = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(do[columns].values), columns=columns)

ttest_ind(do_scaled.favorite_count, do_scaled.user_favourites_count)
#Ttest_indResult(statistic=-1.682257624164912e-16, pvalue=0.9999999999999999)

#pvalue is about 1 : the association is likely due to pure chance
```

here a boxplot to show the distribution of outliers (StandardScaler)

[image]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
do_scaled = pd.DataFrame(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(do[columns].values), columns=columns)

ttest_ind(do_scaled.favorite_count, do_scaled.user_favourites_count)
#Ttest_indResult(statistic=-5.999028611045575, pvalue=2.3988962933916377e-09)

#pvalue is almost 0 (less than 1%) : there is an association between predictor and response.
```

here a boxplot to show the distribution of outliers (MinMaxScaler)

[image]

I don't understand why I get opposite results and don't know how to interpret them.
Can you please advice ?
Can you please help to approach the problem ?

Comment: hypothesis testing is quite different from scaling. The question is poorly designed . Could you  rectify for a correct answer ?

Comment: The question is completely fine. To use Student's test itself in such a way is unusual, something like Spearman's rank correlation would probably be more appropriate here, but o/w the question is fine. And as @user305883 mentions in a comment below, it does not make sense to t-test against standartized populations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, T-test null hypothesis is that there are no differences between means of two samples. And p-value is the probability to observe the data, given that the null hypothesis is correct, so if p-value is small - you are likely to reject the null hypothesis. So in your case it is actually vice-versa to what you wrote:

- In case of `StandardScaler` your test says that "*two samples are taken from the distributions with the same mean*"^[1].
- And in case of `MinMaxScaler` it says that "two samples are unlikely to be taken from the distributions with the same mean".

Now to the second part, **why** you get this result. The answer is actually quite straightforward. To compute Student's statistics one use 3 parameters (6 in case of comparing means of two samples): Mean of the sample, Variance (or standard deviation) of the sample and the size of the sample^[2]. `StandardScaler` applies z-scoring:

$$
X_{\text{standartized}} = \frac{X - \text{mean}(X)}{\text{std}(X)}
$$

thus, after standartization both of the columns have zero mean and unit variance, therefore Student t-test says that means of two samples are the same (because *they are* the same and equal to 0).

Conversely, `MinMaxScaler`:

$$
X_{\text{minmax}} = \frac{X - \text{min}(X)}{\text{max(X)} - \text{min(X)}}
$$

does not make niether mean, nor variance of two samples to be equal (it makes minimal value of the sample to be equal to 0 and maximal to 1), therefore Student t-test says that they are different.

[1] To be more precise your results says that you can not reject the null hypothesis (you could never accept a null hypothesis in statistical testing).

[2] You could check the technicalities of the t-test on wiki page for Welch's t-test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test (Unpaired independent T-test for two samples of different sizes with different variance, which is an appropriate version of the test in your case)

Comment: Thank you! So, it does not make sense to t-test against standardised populations, correct ? because `t-test = (mean1 - mean2) / (std(differences between paired data) / sqrt(sample size) )` and mean1 equals mean2 that equal to zero, in the case above.

Comment: Exactly right. Since the goal of t-test is to compare the means of two populations if their means are equal you will always end up with p-value equal to 1 for any degrees of freedom (=independent of populations sizes)

Comment: @Anvar The hypothesis does not depend upon type of scaling as you claim.